# How can i add this icon to my action bar?

Tags: android, icons, android-toolbar

How can i add this icon to my action bar? Is it one of standard?

For example in this item.

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_edit"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="Ok"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
    android:visible="true"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via the `theme` `xml` layout by adding this to your **`style.xml`** file:

```
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
   <item name="icon">@drawable/actionbar_logo</item>
  </style>
```

Or adding this programmatically inside your activity by adding this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```